# How to determine if a function approaches the dirac delta function?

Tags: dirac-delta

To my question:

There are many functions that represent the Dirac delta "function", like the square wave function:

$$\delta_n(t)=n, -\frac{1}{2n}<t<\frac{1}{2n}$$

And clearly for any value of $n$: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt\delta_n(t)=1$$

and in the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\delta_n(t)=0, \forall t $ except $t=0$.

So how would i prove this? I do have something in mind that would be simply to evaluate the integral with $n \to \infty$ but I'm not quite sure, so just wanted to ask if this would be correct, and the following all could be proved similarly?

Like the Resonance: $$\delta_n(t)=\frac{n/\pi}{1+n^2t^2}$$
or the Sinc Squared: $$\delta_n(t)=\frac{sin^2(nt}{n\pi t^2}$$
or the Gaussian: $$\delta_n(T)=\frac{n}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-{n^2t^2}}$$

But the following example couldn't be evaluated that way and so i was just wondering if there is a general method? And How would you show that this function is a representation of the Dirac delta function?

$$\frac{e^-\frac{x^2}{\epsilon^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}\epsilon}, \epsilon > 0$$

Comment: Explore $\int\, \delta_n\, f$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for smooth functions $f$.

Comment: Try proving that if $h\in L^1, h_n(x)=nh(nx)$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty h_n(x)\phi(x)dx=\phi(0)$ for all $\phi$ continuous and bounded.

Comment: I think that "Merry Christmas!" doesn't belong in a post. It probably belongs in a comment.

Comment: by usign normal methods from real analysis? simply evaluate the integral with $n->\infty$?

Comment: @mathlander The OP was being friendly.  I don't believe that friendliness is forbidden in a posted question, is it?

Comment: Can someone give me an example on how to do one of those?